# User login in multitenant DBs on symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, multi-tenant, saas

*First of all: sorry about my english.... i'm improving it :).*

Hi! I have a problem with login provider in symfomy. Please, help :(

I have a app SaaS with multitenant DBs (a DB for client) that with a service  listener (onKernel) dispatch the users to the correct BD.

I have defined in parameters.yml a DB:

```
database_host: xxxxx
database_port: xxxxx
database_name: my_db
database_user: xxxxx
database_password: xxxxx
database_driver: pdo_mysql
```

The users that must log are in the differents tenants DBs (like client_1, client_2, .... and my_db defined on parameters.yml Every DB with their Users table). But where symfony do the login action it goes to the DB defined on parameters.yml, not on the tenant BD. If the user don't exist on my_db it's impossible to do the login.

I tried to do a UserRespository changing the security.yml but it doesn't works.

There are any way to select a determinated BD (not the defined on parameters.yml) before the login_check action in order to dispacth the login event to the correct BD?

Thanks a lot to the community!!!

Comment: Hello; by the acronym `BD`, does really mean `database`? If so, you should change to `DB` instead. So as I understand it, you have 2 databases, and some users need to connect to a second database? Is that correct?

Comment: @AlvinBunk I figured he does mean DB, since BD seems to be the Spanish abbreviation.

Comment: @AlvinBunk  Yes! I'm sorry, BD is in spanish. I've edited the question.

Comment: @AlvinBunk I have a DataBase for each client (tenant). The App si the same for every client. The login of symfony goes to the DB described in parameters.yml but the users are in the differents client's DBs... I have to dispacth the login order. I only fined instrucctions and events after login, not before login :(